# input error in Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

```
t = int(input())
while t:
    qu , pt = input().split(' ')
    qu = int(qu)
    pt = int(pt)
    sd = []
    for i in range(0,qu):
        x = int(input())  # I think I am getting problem in this part of 
        sd.append(x)
    hd , cw = 0 , 0
    diff = pt / 10
    cwk = pt / 2
    for i in range(0,qu):
        if sd[i] <= diff:
            hd += 1
        else:
            if sd[i] >= cwk:
            cw += 1
    if hd == 2 and cw == 1:
        print ('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
    t -= 1
```

When I try to give input like '1 2 3' I get an an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Matrix/Desktop/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    x = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3'
```

Why am I seeing this problem ? How do I rectify this ?

Comment: What do you think it should do what you try to convert "1 2 3" to an integer?

Comment: So how do I rectify this ?

Comment: separate the inputs with an enter key..

Comment: I can't I am suppose to use the input in this way only

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're passing it a string rather than an integer. When you typed "1 2 3," you left spaces, which are considered characters. Spaces cannot be cast as integers. If your set on having the input as number space number space number space, then I suggest you split the sentence at the whitespace into a list.

```
def setence_splitter(user_input):
# splits the input
words = text.split()
```

Now you have the list, words, which will have each individual number. You can call each individual number using its index in words. The first number will be words[0] and so on.

Comment: But when I convert "100 25 1" into list it turns into ['1', '0', '0', '2', '5', '1'] and thus I get a wrong answer. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @Animesh Srivastawa check my newest edit of my answer. I hope this fixes your problem!